# Selecting amount of Placed loan and Cleared loan of the same day in provided table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am building an application that holds user loan information, but the problem is how to select the amount of loan placed and cleared loan of the same day; for example if user place loan at 7:00 AM and cleared it at the same day at 13:00 PM how could I get this loan placed and cleared on this same day?

My example table is:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | user_id | placed_loan | cleared loan | plcd date | cld_date | status
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |   2     |   5000.00   |    0.00      |  19/6/12 |          |   1 
2  |   2     |   0.00      |    4000.00   |          |  19/6/13 |   2
3  |   2     |   2000.00   |    0.00      |  19/6/14 |          |   1
4  |   3     |   4000.00   |    0.00      |  19/6/14 |          |   1
5  |   2     |   0.00      |    3000.00   |          | 19/6/14  |   2
6  |   3     |   0.00      |    2000.00   |          | 19/6/15  |   2 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For example, a user with ID 2 on 19/6/14 placed a loan of 2000.00 and cleared a loan of 3000.00 this is to say that amount of loan placed on 19/6/14 and cleared on 19/6/14 for the user 2 is 2000.00; and remaining 1000.00 was of 19/6/12.

How could I select this data?

Comment: 7AM, 13PM? where does this data come from? you mention `today` as the where, but then you example contradicts that by selecting events from 19/6/12 and 19/6/14. it sounds like the date is irrelevant, according to your example, and you just want the result of `placed_loan` - `cleared_loan` for a user with a specific id??

Comment: Sorry for confusing you by the term today; simply my goal is to identify amount of loan placed and re-payed on same day; thanks

Comment: so to be clear, for user2 on 19/6/14, the result would be -1000? 2000 (placed) - 3000 (cleared)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Hello @NicoHaase; As data shown in the table user cleared loan by amount of 3000.00 at 19/06/14 but on the same day he placed the loan of 2000; this mean that amount of loan placed and cleared on the same day is only 2000.00 and the rest amount of 1000.00 paid the remaining loan of 19/06/12; now, how could get this amount of 2000.00 through query?

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the loan placed-cleared before the date. Then subtract that from cleared on the date.

```
    $this->db->select('(SUM(placed_loan) - SUM(cleared_loan))');
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('plcd_date <', $date);
    $subquery = $this->db->get_compiled_select('yourtablename');
    $this->db->select("placed_loan, (cleared_loan - ($subquery)) as cleared_to_date");
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('plcd_date', $date);
    $q = $this->db->get('yourtablename');
    if ($q->num_rows() == 0) {
        die('no rows');
    }
    $res = $q->row();
    echo "placed: $res->placed_loan"; // 2000
    echo "cleared_to_date: $res->cleared_to_date"; // 2000
    exit;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Alex; but my problem is still there; as data shown in the table user cleared loan by amount of 3000.00 at 19/06/14 but on the same day he placed the loan of 2000; this mean that amount of loan placed and cleared on the same day is only 2000.00 and the rest amount of 1000.00 paid the remaining loan of 19/06/12; now, how could get this amount of 2000.00 through query? thanks.

Comment: Hello @Alex; I have tried this code but result is 0.00

Comment: $date = '2019-06-14';
        $user_id = 1;
        $this->db->select('(SUM(placed_loan) - SUM(cleared_loan)) as net');
        $this->db->where('loan_added_on <=', $date);
        $this->db->where('loan_cleared_on <=', $date);
        $this->db->where('customer_name', $user_id);
        $q = $this->db->get('customers_loans');
        if ($q->num_rows() == 0) {
            echo 'no results';
        } else {
            $net = $q->row()->net;
            echo $net;
        }

Comment: yea i just don't your "formula". can you write it out mathematically? i'm not sure how 2000-3000 = 2000, or how 5000+2000-4000-3000 = 2000

Comment: i mean technically, after the 13th he only had 1000 left on his loan to pay, then he placed a loan and subsequently paid everything of on the 14th... hence net 0

Comment: Ok @Alex; let me try to put it clear in simple words
Let say customer borrowed 5000.00 on the date 19/06/15
Then he repaid amount of 4000.00 on the date 19/06/13 (This means he is still owed 1000.00)
Then on 19/06/14 he placed another loan of 2000.00 (Now he is owed 1000.00 + 2000.00 = 3000.00)
On the same day (19/06/14) he paid 3000.00
Therefore, amount of loan placed and cleared on the same day is 2000.00 (3000.00 - 1000.00); What I want to get is this amount of loan placed and cleared on the same day (not total placed loan or total cleared loan) as it is required to be used in my app.

Comment: Thank you @Alex for your contribution; the the answer I have posted: thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT A.id as id, A.user_id as userid , A.plcd_date as date , SUM(A.placed_loan) as loan_amt , SUM(B.cleared_loan) clr_amt FROM `user_loan` as A , `user_loan` as B WHERE A.plcd_date = B.cld_date GROUP BY A.plcd_date, A.user_id
```

- Result   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqAzc.png)
- Data     [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7xx9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone who participated to give the solution of my problem:

```
 $data['financial_year_start'] = '2019-06-10';
        $data['recon_date'] = '2019-06-12';
        //$user_id = 1;
        $this->db->select('(SELECT SUM(placed_loan) FROM customers_loans WHERE loan_added_on >="'.$data['financial_year_start'].'" AND loan_added_on <"'.$data['recon_date'].'") AS plcd_before', FALSE);
        $this->db->select('(SELECT SUM(placed_loan) FROM customers_loans WHERE loan_added_on ="'.$data['recon_date'].'") AS plcd_today', FALSE);
        $this->db->select('(SELECT SUM(cleared_loan) FROM customers_loans WHERE loan_added_on >="'.$data['financial_year_start'].'" AND loan_added_on <"'.$data['recon_date'].'") AS cld_before', FALSE);
        $this->db->select('(SELECT SUM(cleared_loan) FROM customers_loans WHERE loan_added_on ="'.$data['recon_date'].'") AS cld_today', FALSE);
        $q = $this->db->get()->result_array();;


       $data['plcd_bbf'] = $q[0]['plcd_before'] - $q[0]['cld_before'];
       $data['plc_cld_today'] = $q[0]['cld_today'] - $data['plcd_bbf'];
       echo $data['plc_cld_today']; // This is the amount of loan placed and cleared on the same day
```